# Как перейти на новую версию React?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

Как перейти на новую версию React, если ранее выполнял `npm run eject`?

Comment: npm i react react-dom

Comment: Не понятна суть вопроса, в чем конкретно у Вас проблема?

Comment: @Alexander Zaytsev, после того как я сделал eject в create-react-app, из package.json пропали react и react-dom. И npm i react react-dom не помогает.
Поэтому теперь к примеру не могу использовать react context